# Scale Angular Material website (on Android)

Tags: android, css, angular, angular-material

On Chrome (Edge, Firefox, ...) on desktop I can zoom web sites and all items, sizes, relations will be zoomed accordingly.

Now I need the same feature on an Android handset using Chrome (or some other Android Browser). Since there is no setting in Chrome/Android to zoom a website (just some non-working text scaling) I'm looking for a way to scale from the app.

So my question is: how can I seamless scale an Angular Material app/website to, say, 125% or 150% so all Items, sizes etc. will scale accordingly?

Can I somehow set some base scaling or add some base css to scale up / zoom an Angular Material App/Page?

Comment: A quick fix could be to scale the entire viewport https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp but I guess you'd like to scale elements individually within the viewport.

Comment: I want to scale the full app, so scaling the viewport would be ok, thanks!